# How I get some pokéstops in my town?

Tags: pokemon-go

My town doesn't have any pokéstops or gyms. Somehow it has 700 players but no pokéstops or gyms. Players can't go out to get some pokéballs or anything else because it's too far away from my town.

How can I get pokéstops or gyms added to my town?

Answer (score 0):

According to Niantic, [they are not accepting submissions for new pokestops](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221968408-Reporting-Pok%C3%A9Stop-or-Gym-Issues). Unfortunately, they've elected to design Pokemon Go so that it only works for those who live in or visit densely populated metropolitan areas. For the time being you are out of luck if you want to play Pokemon Go in your own town.

Comment: They did have a request form for some time, though, so it isn't out of the question that it will be reopened.

Comment: I think they are moving towards monetizing pokestops. The best bet would be that they open up this option to smaller businesses, so that those in small towns can afford to put one up. http://gizmodo.com/it-looks-like-pokemon-go-is-pursuing-a-partnership-with-1783580645